# Superimpose a quadratic function on top a ggplot2 object which is facet_wrapped

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one with a global mean temperature recording for each month in every year since 1880-2023 and one with a quadratic model in a tidy format (i.e, one column for each month, one column for the intercept and two columns for the model estimates (beta and beta squared).

I want to superimpose the quadratic function specific to each month on top of temperature recordings for each year for each month.

You can access the data I have used like this through the tidytuesdayR package:

```
library(tidytuesdayR)
library(tidyverse)

tuesdata <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load(2023, week = 28)
global_temps <- tuesdata$global_temps
```

This is the code that clean and prepares the data:

```
# Clean data

global_temps <- global_temps |> 
  janitor::clean_names()

# Pivot

global_temps <- global_temps |> 
    pivot_longer(
        c(jan:dec),
        names_to = "month",
        values_to = "temperature"
    ) |> 
    select(
      year, 
      month, 
      temperature
    ) |> 
  mutate(
    month = (str_to_title(month))
  )

# Order months

month_order <- c(
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
)

global_temps <- global_temps |> 
  mutate(
    month = factor(month, levels = month_order)
  )
```

This part computes the quadratic function for each month:

```
# Model the increase in temperature with a quadratic term

global_temp_quad <- global_temps |> 
  group_by(month) |> 
  nest() |> 
  mutate(
    model = map(data, ~ lm(temperature ~ poly(year, 2, raw = TRUE), data = .x))
  )

global_temp_quad <- global_temp_quad |>
  mutate(
    coef = map(model, broom::tidy)
  ) |> 
  unnest(coef) |> 
  select(
    term,
    estimate
  )

# Pivot wider

global_temp_quad <- global_temp_quad |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = term,
    values_from = estimate
  ) |> 
  rename(
    intercept = "(Intercept)",
    year = "poly(year, 2, raw = TRUE)1",
    year_2 = "poly(year, 2, raw = TRUE)2"
  ) |> 
  ungroup()
```

This is the code that creates the plot using the two data frames presented above:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = global_temps,
    aes(
      x = year,
      y = temperature
    ), 
    show.legend = FALSE,
    size = 1.5,
    alpha = 1,
    shape = 1
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(
    title = "Global surface temperatures (1890-2023)",
    subtitle = "Temperature is recorded as deviation from the mean temperature for 1890-1950",
    source = "Data from NASA/GISS",
    x = NULL,
    y = "Deviation from mean temperature (Celsius)"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ month) +
  geom_function(
    data = global_temp_quad,
    aes(
      group = interaction(month)
    ),
    color = "red",
    alpha = 0.7,
    show.legend = FALSE,
    fun = function(x) {
      global_temp_quad$intercept +
      global_temp_quad$year * x +
      global_temp_quad$year_2 * x^2
    }
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(1890, 2020, 40)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(-0.5, 1.5)
  )
```

Now, I would greatly appreciate if anyone had a solution to my problem:

**How can I model each function to be specific to the month in the facet_wrapped ggplot2 plot?**

Comment: `global_temps` does not have columns `month` nor `temperature` and `year` is capitalized. The code doesn't run. Can you make the example reproducible, please?

Comment: Agreed. (I think you might need to `pivot_longer()`?) Also, it would be good if you explicitly included `library(tidyverse)`; some of us like to run examples as a self-contained chunk/don't always have tidyverse loaded ...

Comment: Also, not clear why you aren't "just" using `geom_smooth` with `method = "lm"` to superimpose these curves?

Comment: @RuiBarradas The post has now been updated to be reproducible.

Comment: @BenBolker It works as you've proposed, but I am interested in the manual approach in this case.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940210/can-ggplot2-geom-function-be-faceted-across-arg-values) (googled "geom_function facet")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have any luck with `geom_function` because this requires the *same*  function to be applied to each panel, but you would need a *separate* function for each panel.

I would create the curve data myself and add lines to the plot:

```r
curve_data <- global_temps |>
  group_by(month) |>
  summarize(first = min(year), last = max(year), .groups = "keep") |>
  inner_join(global_temp_quad |> 
               select(month, i = intercept, b1 = year, b2 = year_2),
             "month") |>
  reframe(xx = seq(first, last, length.out = 100),
          i, b1, b2) |>
  mutate(month, xx, yy = i + b1 * xx + b2 * xx ^ 2, .keep = "none")

## assume p is your plot without the geom_function part
## (just made the line thicker to see it better)
p +
  geom_line(data = curve_data, aes(xx, yy),
    color = "red",
    alpha = 0.7,
    linewidth = 2,
    show.legend = FALSE)
```

---

Using the idea linked by @Ben you can (mis-) use `geom_function` by supplying modified data, disregarding the help of `geom_function`:

> `data: Ignored by ‘stat_function()’, do not use.`

You add several `geom_functions` where the facetting variable is set to the respective panel like this:

```r
gfs <- global_temp_quad |>
  group_by(month) |>
  group_map(~ geom_function(data = global_temps |> mutate(month = .y$month),
                   color = "red", alpha = .7, show.legend = FALSE, linewidth = 2,
                   fun = \(x) .x$intercept + .x$year * x + .x$year_2 * x ^ 2))
```

Now, `gfs` contains 12 `geom_functions` each with different coefficients and the data slot overridden such that it applies only to its respective panel. You can add them to the plot `p` with `Reduce`:

```r
Reduce(`+`, gfs, p)
```

[image: Facetted plot showing year on the x-axis and temperature on the y axis and a red smooth line for each panel]